# How do I apply a texture to an object in Cycles with nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, node-editor

I know nothing about nodes, so I tried to use them. I UV-ed my monkey head, and then I colored on it. I brought the image back into Blender, added a new material, then went to the node editor and opened the image. The image shows the two original nodes that were there. How do I set it up and get the image on to the monkey?

[image: This shows the UVs and the nodes!]

Answer (score 2):

You are in the *Compositing* node view right now which is for post-processing.  You need to switch to *Material* nodes to edit your object's material.  To switch to material nodes click on the material icon at the bottom of the node editor.

[image]

Now you can add your texture with an *Image Texture* node and plug it into whatever shader[s] you are using.

[image]